# I'm trying to add a submenu item into my Navigation Drawer, what is the easiest way to implement this using the code I have so far?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer, submenu

Here is the MainActivity that I have, which has my Navigation Drawer. Is it as simple as adding sub menu items to the Drawer Menu XML or the Navigation Drawer View. Or is it that I will have to add it programmaticaly in my code using an expandable list view. Any help will be greatly appreciated. When I click the item on the navigation drawer, I want it to drop down to more selections?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, new HomeFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Drift Fan");
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.Home:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new HomeFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home Fragment");
                        item.setCheckable(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.my_account:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new myAccountFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Account");
                        item.setCheckable(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_about:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new AboutDriftingFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("About Drifting");
                        item.setCheckable(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_shop:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new ShopFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Shop");
                        item.setCheckable(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_news:
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new NewsFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("News");
                        item.setCheckable(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                }


                return false;
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.drawer_menu, menu);
        return true;



    }
}
```

Below are the Layout Files, the drawer Menu Layout where I have my items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <group android:id="@+id/group7">
        <item android:id="@+id/Home" android:title="Home"></item>>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group6">
        <item android:id="@+id/my_account" android:title="My Account"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group5">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_news" android:title="News"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group1">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_live" android:title="Live"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group2">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_media" android:title="Media"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group3">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_calendar" android:title="Calendar"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group4">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_results" android:title="Results"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group8">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_about" android:title="About Drifting"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group9">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_shop" android:title="Shop"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group10">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_socialmedia" android:title="SocialMedia"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group11">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_fanzone" android:title="Fanzone"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group12">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_map" android:title="Navigation to Event"></item>
    </group>


</menu>
```

Below is my activity Main XML Layout which has my Navigation Drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"

            />
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_container">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#000"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="#fff"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add this in **menu layout** file:

```
<item android:title="Submenu title">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_submenu_1"
                android:title="submenutitle1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_timer_auto_black_36dp"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_submenu_2"
                android:title="submenutitle2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_black_36dp"/>

        </menu>
    </item>
```

So your **menu** be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <group android:id="@+id/group7">
        <item android:id="@+id/Home" android:title="Home"></item>>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group6">
        <item android:id="@+id/my_account" android:title="My Account"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group5">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_news" android:title="News"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group1">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_live" android:title="Live"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group2">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_media" android:title="Media"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group3">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_calendar" android:title="Calendar"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group4">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_results" android:title="Results"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group8">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_about" android:title="About Drifting"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group9">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_shop" android:title="Shop"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group10">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_socialmedia" android:title="SocialMedia"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group11">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_fanzone" android:title="Fanzone"></item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group12">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_map" android:title="Navigation to Event"></item>
    </group>

<item android:title="Submenu title">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_submenu_1"
                    android:title="submenutitle1"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_timer_auto_black_36dp"/>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_submenu_1"
                    android:title="submenutitle2"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_black_36dp"/>

            </menu>
        </item>


</menu>
```